# How to prevent parent div opacity from affecting child divs in a Primeng Carousel?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I'm having trouble looking to prevent the **"opacity"** state of the **parent div** from being inherited by the **child divs**.

In this particular code, I was looking for the opacity to not affect the element buttons. In my original code I have multiple states using "radial-gradient" so I haven't had the necessary knowledge to adapt the code using the RGB solution, ::before pseudo element or the "position: relative" solution.
I will be very grateful to anyone who can help me.

I attach an example code
[Code example in Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-carousel-demo-b1336s?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because putting opacity on the parent all childs will be affected too, but with the current layout example you can just do a background opacity instead. here is the the modified css. From you stackblitz example:

```
.product-item {
  .product-item-content {
    border: 1px solid var(--surface-d);
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 0.3rem;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2rem 0;
    background: transparent
      radial-gradient(circle at left bottom, #009eea 0%, #004186 100%);
    
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    &:hover{
      background: transparent
      radial-gradient(circle at left bottom, #009eea80 0%, #00418680 100%);
    }
  }

  .product-image {
    width: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  }
}
```

note that the 80 after you colors represent 50% opacity.

Also if you have other elements you want to give opacity you must add selectors for those as well within the hover selector.

Comment: First of all I want to thank you for the good answer, I was unaware that 80 after the colors represented 50% opacity. Your solution is the most optimal that I load at the moment, although I would like to know if there will be a way without having to add 80 after the colors since I have about 30 different color styles.

Comment: you could probably use rgba() or hsla() colors instead to make the 50% more clear

Answer (score 0):

Create new empty div under buttons with opacity 0.
On hover make it 0.5

I think that your approach will not work because of Cascading nature of CSS.

Comment: I tried that using position relative in the new div but since it is a carousel which adapts according to the responsive the values ​​of left and rigth positions changes so it didn't work for me.

Answer (score -1):

[How to make a radial gradient with transparency in css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32059991/how-to-make-a-radial-gradient-with-transparency-in-css)

I found this, looks like you can use RGBA for the gradient colors. If your background contains the transparency, you should be able to remove opacity.